# Handle processing of a large number of incoming mails

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, parallel-processing, architecture

We're trying to create an app that scans incoming mails of employees for malware.

We'll have 2 servers on Auto-scale, with AWS SQS between them.
One server for request handling (RS), and the other for processing the emails (PS).

It's like this:

S1-S2-S3-...(RS)

===SQS===

S4-S5-S6...(PS)

This is how it works:

1. RS subscribes to a large number of outlook mailboxes using Microsoft's Graph API.
   For each email user receives, an RS route gets hit.
2. RS receives hit & pushes notifications in SQS.
3. PS long-polls, retrieves 10 messages at once, fetch emails using Graph API, and perform processing on them concurrently.
   It'll save the email to S3bucket if malicious.

Considerations:-

If I have 400,000 users with 10 emails on average per day, we'll get 40,00,000 hits per day.

For request handling, I'm thinking of using hyper-express, instead of express.

For processing, I'm worried.
I'm thinking of just using the cluster module for now, and see where that goes.

BUT, I was reading about Azure Event Hubs.
They say that they are scalable, and should be used when you have a large number of subscriptions.
It looks like SQS FIFO.
And I've not found a way by which the event hub will directly subscribe to the mailboxes.

Any guidance/help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Graph Subscriptions support directly sending change notifications to Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-event-hubs?tabs=change-notifications-eventhubs-azure-cli%2Chttp) which removes the need for the `RS` service in your solution.

Instead, your `PS` service would read from [Azure Event Hubs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/) directly and process the messages. Since Event Hubs (like Kafka) are durable and allow multiple consumers, you can deploy an [Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) for example that processes and scales with the number of the messages that come in.

With Azure Functions, you can simply use [the binding for Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5) which when used and running on the consumption plan, auto-scales your function app to deal with the incoming load.